# Do American universities generally sponsor H1B visas for staff?

Tags: united-states, visa

Do top American universities (such as NYU, etc.) sponsor H1B visa petitions for staff position? If yes, what type of jobs are sponsored in staff positions?

Comment: I edited it to make it more generalizable and apropos for this SE.

Comment: The key here is the nature and duration of the job.  You simply can't sponsor an employee for an H-1B visa if the position doesn't require at least a Bachelor's degree.  You can't sponsor without being able to assert that qualified US citizens/residents weren't available- for most low level administrative and IT positions, that can be tough.  It also makes little sense to sponsor for an H-1B visa if the position is for a limited time- thus many universities won't sponsor an H-1B visa for a one or two year post-doc or visiting assistant professor position.

Comment: Actually, the sites I looked at seemed to suggest it happens pretty regularly.  But yes, absolutely must be specialized and long term.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  A simple google search for "[H1-B university staff](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=h1b%20visa%20university%20staff)" links to a bunch of federal and school-specific policies.  It goes without saying these roles are reserved for people with "specialized knowledge," etc.  Also a link to a similarish question about faculty is [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/21338/h-1b-visa-sponsorship-by-universities).

You asked "what type" and I missed that the first time around.  [Here is a link to a page](http://www.myvisajobs.com/Visa-Sponsor/New-York-University/384234.htm) that explains H1B jobs open at NYU.  Not all but mostly faculty positions.